# How to migrate / transfer / upgrade existing google account to google workspace account under same email address on my personal domain?

Tags: email, migration, google-workspace, google-accounts

I currently have a personal Google Account using an email address on a domain name I own. For this particular email address, I also currently have email set up with Yahoo!, but I want to migrate to using G Suite instead.

Google does not seem to allow you to create a Google Workspace account when you have a personal Google Account under the same email.

1. How do I set up a Google Workspace account and G Suite for this email address?
2. How do I ensure that I don't lose the data associated with my personal Google Account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to sign up for a new Workspace account at https://workspace.google.com/signup/businessstarter/welcome?hl=en using your domain name and a temporary Admin email address gsuiteadmin@ (this is required to prevent conflicts with the existing consumer account). Once the setup is complete and the domain is verified, you can use the [Unmanaged users transfer tool](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6178640?visit_id=637565268590073161-2702078845&rd=1#zippy=%2Cfind-users-with-potential-conflicting-accounts) to transfer the consumer account including the compatible services. Make sure to update the [MX records](https://support.google.com/a/answer/140034?hl=en) so messages are delivered to Google servers instead.

Comment: Does it matter what the temporary email username is or was "gsuiteadmin" a specifically required name for some reason?

Comment: It can be any temporary email username as long as it is different than your existing email address so it doesn't create any conflicts.